# How to check if integer array overlaps with int4range?

Tags: postgresql, array, range-types

PostgreSQL version: 9.5

I am trying to write a query that will check if an array of specified decades overlaps in a range. For example, I'd like to find all of the people employed at a company in the 1980's OR the 2000's. Let's say I have two `date` columns: `start_date` and `end_date`. Here's my best attempt so far:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM date_table 
WHERE int4range(EXTRACT(DECADE from start_date)::int, 
                EXTRACT(DECADE from end_date)::int) && (int4range(198, 200))
```

This query will check for anyone employed in the 1980s, 1990s, or the 2000s. I don't want to compare a range to another range; instead, it should be checking if **any** of the values in the array is contained in the range. How can I accomplish this? Is there another way I could be approaching this problem?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer by joanolo, my working query is:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM date_table 
WHERE int4range(EXTRACT(DECADE from start_date)::int, 
                EXTRACT(DECADE from end_date)::int, '[]') @> ANY(ARRAY[198, 200])
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Let's consider this as *set* operations. Overlaps (as in your title) means {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} *has a not null intersection* with range[4, 5]. On the other hand, I don't know what it exactly means *an array exists in the range* (as in your text). Does this mean, it *is contained in*. That would mean {1,2, .. 8} is not contained in range[4, 5].

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In your example, I would like to check if either 4 or 5 is in the range, but I'd like to do this with an array. So if my array is `[1, 3, 4]`, I'd like to check if either 1, 3, or 4 is contained in the range of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`.

Comment: So you actually are checking for *not null intersection*.

Comment: You'll probably need a functional  index for `int4range(EXTRACT(DECADE from start_date)::int, EXTRACT(DECADE from end_date)::int, '[]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21104) and [`ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21127) array element quantifiers, together with the [`@>` contains element](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) range operator.

If you want to know if *ANY* element of the array lies within your range, which is what, according to your comments, is what I interpret you want, you can use:

```
SELECT
    int4range(5, 8, '[]') @> ANY(ARRAY[1, 3, 5, 7]) AS some_are_in
```

(in this case, this will return TRUE, because both 5 and 7 are part of the range)

This nearly translates your request (but reversing it): *Does the range contain **ANY** of the elements of the array?*

---

If you would like to know that they're *all* in, you'd use `ALL` instead of `ANY`:

```
SELECT
    int4range(5, 8, '[]') @> ALL(ARRAY[1, 3, 5, 7]) AS all_are_in
```

(in this case, this will return false, because 1 and 3 are *not* part of the range)

You can find these and some other examples at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=78c43ce181b64cfb4095eef91af88fc5)*

Answer (score 1):

You may have better performance unrolling it and dropping the range operation.

```
WHERE x1 BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
  OR x2 BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

The range operation is fast, but only if you have a separate indexes on

```
int4range(EXTRACT(DECADE from start_date)::int, EXTRACT(DECADE from end_date)::int;
```

Whereas the `WHERE BETWEEN` can make use of the indexes available. It's arguably a bad idea to add indexes that pick `decade` arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and insight on performance! I don't have any indexes on the `start_date` or `end_date` columns. I extract the decade because that is the only part of the date that is important in this query. My example was simple in nature; I actually need this query to work for any number of decades specified in the array. Would your approach handle that case without requiring a dynamically crafted query?

Comment: No, you have to dynamically craft the query to use this method.